# Proxy settings for gitlab-omnibus

Tags: proxy, gitlab

Hi Just wondering how I can make gitlab-onmibus use a proxy server for operations that require it to go out to the internet e.g. cloning repositories from github and gravitar.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being resolved in 7.2.  A new feature allowing you to specify ENV vars that will be available to the gitlab services.